# Error when trying to use Facebook managed groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm getting this error when logging in using facebook login

> Invalid Scopes: user_managed_groups. This message is only shown to
>   developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if
>   present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

It was working perfectly 2 days ago but suddenly it stopped I did not change a single line of code what could be the problem?

Comment: Your app needs to be in dev mode now for you to be able to test with permissions that have not been reviewed yet.

Comment: @CBroe I just checked my app is still in development mode but I still get the error

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_managed_groups says this permission is deprecated, as they are working on a new access model for groups. Also says there it is “for testing only” now - not sure when that was last updated though, maybe they removed it altogether by now (or for newly created apps.) Anyway, doesn’t seem to be much point in developing anything based on it now to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of accessing user-managed groups is to use the `groups_access_member_info` permission and using this query `me?fields=groups{administrator,name}` then you can filter the data in your app to only display groups where administrator is equal to true.